# How to Stop Duplicating items in java combo box

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

well I am making a POS system for a stationary shop, the client need to enter the photocopy sales details to his system so what I did was I entered the paper format size color and price respectively to MySQL database. for example

A4 single side B/W $1
A4 double side B/w $2
A4 single side color $3
A4 double color $4

now the problem is when I a populate the combo box with a column the data will be duplicated

for example
A4
A4
A4
A4

that is because I entered 4 times the A4 to database,what I need to do is when I click the combo box I should only show 1 A4

I connected the combo box with database

```
   try {

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/photocopy","root","");

        String sql="SELECT * FROM `prices`";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs =pstmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){


        String pathayo = rs.getString("color");



        jComboBox3.addItem(pathayo);




        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

I need to show only A4 once not 4 times

[check this images plz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diF9s.png)

[check this images plz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vofdV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is root cause. You have 4 columns, however, you retrieve only 1 column 4 times.  Use below as example.

```java
while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        }
```

In your case, fixing is very simple:

```java
String pathayo = null;
while(rs.next()){
   pathayo = rs.getString("color");        
}
if(pathayo != null) jComboBox3.addItem(pathayo);
```

Comment: You mean if I take jComboBox3.addItem(pathayo); it will not add all the items but only once sure ?

Comment: Sir if you can please check the database photo which have attached

Comment: I tried it but cannot beacuae when i move jComboBox3.addItem(pathayo); out from the loop the pathayo string is not recongized , the pathayo string is a search result of a database

Comment: How to fix it, i need only  one row

Comment: offer your an answer, try it.